# My MySql, php combination is not working properly

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

So i wanted to make a social network and followed some youtube videos from codeetastic, but at the forth movie, my login function didn't react properly. Do you guys have any idea?
(index.php)

```
<?php include "templates/nav.php"; ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
        <title>EverTime</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css"/>
        <script src="js/main.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="middle">
            <h1 id="welcome">Welcome to EverTime!</h1>
            <form action="parse/login.php" method="post">
                <input type="text" name="username" id="username" placeholder="Username..."/>
                <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password..."/>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Log in"/><a id="link" href="register.php">Create an account</a>
            </form>
        </div>  
    </body>
</html>
```

(login.php)

```
<?php
//connect
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("evertime") or die(mysql_error());

//login script
    if(isset($_POST['username'])) {
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];

        $md5pass = md5($password);

        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE username='$username' AND password='$md5pass'");
        $get = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);

        if($get = ""){
            echo "User does not exist";
        } else {
            echo "User does exist";
        }
    }
?>
```

(config.php)

```
<?php

//connect to database
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("evertime") or die(mysql_error());
?>
```

Btw, i am using xampp with php 5.4.15 and mysql (not mysql**i**)

Comment: "it doesn't work" does **not** qualify as a problem. What doesn't work? What error do you get? What have you done to troubleshoot it? Also, that tutorial is obsolete as the code it tells you to use is deprecated and will be going away soon. Find another tutorial to use.

Comment: mysql_* functions are deprecated, use mysqli or PDO instead

Comment: `username=admin'; --`. Thanks. Now I'm logged in as admin - so nice of you! :) (*hint: You should escape your variables because else everyone can do this and "hack" your site. Look up "SQL Injection".*)

Answer (score 4):

```
    if($get = ""){
```

should probably be

```
    if($get == ""){
```